# Is there a way to tell how far behind a Lambda event mapping for Kinesis is?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a Lambda subscribing to a Kinesis stream through an event source mapping.

My understanding is that the event source mapping stores the last processed record id (per shard) as a part of its internal state and advances it once a batch of records has been successfully processed or the retry limit has been reached.

Is there any way to query the mapping and have it return its current positions in the shards?

Basically, I want to know how far behind the mapping is at a given point in time.

As a fallback option, I could have the Lambda function calculate the delay on each invocation and store it somewhere, but I would prefer to do it outside the Lambda code, if it's possible at all.